# How to get the list of child of child in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to make an arraylist of firebase child. Here is my json data:

```
{

  "Posts" : {

    "4dBtdsgxgMdWahQKLW3dfZ3QYnv110-05-201909:19:00 PM" : {

      "location" : "",
      "postimg" : {
            "0":"http://something.com"
            "1":"http://something.com"
            "2":"http://something.com"
            },
      "uid" : "4dBtdsgxgMdWahQKLW3dfZ3QYnv1"
    },
    "4dBtdsgxgMdWahQKLW3dfZ3QYnv110-05-201909:28:48 PM" : {
      "location" : "",
      "postimg" : {
            "0":"http://something.com"
            "1":"http://something.com"
            },
      "uid" : "4dBtdsgxgMdWahQKLW3dfZ3QYnv1"
    },

    "jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy224-05-201912:29:14 AM" : {

      "location" : "",
      "postimg" : {
            "0":"http://something.com"
            "1":"http://something.com"
            "2":"http://something.com"
            "3":"http://something.com"
            },
      "uid" : "jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy2"
    },
    "jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy228-05-201902:15:20 AM" : {

      "location" : "",
     "postimg" : {
            "0":"http://something.com"
            "1":"http://something.com"
            },
      "uid" : "jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy2"
    },
    "jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy229-05-201912:27:16 AM" : {

      "location" : "",
     "postimg" : {
            "0":"http://something.com"
            "1":"http://something.com"
            },
      "uid" : "jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy2"
    },

  },
}
```

Now i want to make arraylist of postimg child of specific uid of Posts node.
Suppose `CurrentUserId` is `jOt0sDoVvwcse3yTbpByxnrX2xy2`.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
    View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos_user_fragment_tab, null);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUserId=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    UserRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(CurrentUserId);

    PostRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    final List<ImageView> imageViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    imageViewList.add(firstPhoto);
    imageViewList.add(secondPhoto);
    imageViewList.add(thirdPhoto);

    PostRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(CurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot ing : dataSnapshot.child("postimg").getChildren())
                {
                    list.add(ing.getValue().toString());
                }



            int index = 0;
            for(ImageView imageView : imageViewList) {
                if (index == list.size()) break;
                Picasso.get().load(list.get(index)).into(imageView);
                index++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




    return view;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: by this code app is not crash but images are not displaying

Comment: You mentioned in your question that the app is crashing.

Comment: but by the guidene @P.juni i update my code, than app crash is gone but images is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because if list is empty then there is no position for `get()` method.

You should either check if list has valid length and then fill the imageViews, but then you can have 1 image, 2 images, 3 or more, so you could think for some workaround, e.g. create list of imageViews to fill into.

```
List<ImageView> imageViewList = new ArrayList<>();
imageViewList.add(firstPhoto);
imageViewList.add(secondPhoto);
imageViewList.add(thirdPhoto);

for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot ing: childDataSnapshot.child("postimg").getChildren()) {
        list.add(ing.getValue().toString());
    }

    int index = 0;
    for(ImageView imageView : imageViewList) {
        if(index == list.size()) break;
        Picasso.get().load(list.get(index)).into(imageView);
        index++;
    }
}
```

But again, remember that if there will be 4 images and you will have 3 imageViews there will be crash as there won't be fourth item in the imageViewList

Comment: my answer stays the same :) you could iterate through the `childDataSnapshot` as you do or iterate basing on the `imageViewList` firstly, depends what fits best for your need

Comment: you answer is right but im not understanding Imageview list as you say

Comment: i cant understand these three lines
imageViewList.add(firstPhoto);
imageViewList.add(secondPhoto);
imageViewList.add(thirdPhoto);

Comment: maybe we can discuss it chat room -> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194086/pjuni

Comment: not eligible stackoverflow wants 20 reputation for this

Comment: ok see my edit. As far as I understand, there is no maximum number for images in the database, so you can limit it to the count of imageViews you have

Comment: pay attention to your code, you have doubled the `for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren())` - remove the first one

Comment: hey please help

Comment: fix your code :)  dont know what are your errors, but I dont think here should be if you rely carefully on my answer

Comment: please help this